# How do I insert values into two tables using Springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, postman, crud

I have two entities, namely Team and Player. I am very new to Springboot and only followed a video with how to make a basic crud api. However, I am having trouble with creating records with regards to the FK. I am able to create a player, but I do not know how to assign the player to a team. Here is my Player entity: [image]

and here is my team Entity:
[image]

Player Service: [image]

Team Service: [image]

Team Repo: [image]

Player Repo: [image]

I am testing my program in Postman and when I ran this input for a new team: [image]

it created a team, but the player table is still empty. I am not sure on how to proceed with this. Please help!

Comment: where is the code that adds players to the team?

Comment: Try to look at this article, it may help you https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby . Let me know if it solve your problem.